# C++14 Generic lambdas in header file

Tags: c++, header-files, c++14, generic-lambda

I have set of functors like the following:

```
const auto add = [](const auto& x) {
    return [=](const auto& n) { return n + x; };
};
```

Is it right to store them in a header file? (any side effects?)

Comment: yes you can ..... i think there isn't any problem ... did you test it ?

Comment: Since this is actually a definition of a variable (with a strange type, but still) - won't including the header in multiple cpp files yield a problem of multiple definitions in separate compilation units?

Comment: It doesn't cause problem since it is const and as I've read thereby it is linked internally.

Comment: This is OK by itself, except that using them in any inline functions/templates/etc. with external linkage results in an ODR violation.

Comment: Is there any way to store such lambdas while preventing from creating two copies of them when included in two header files? (since they're generic lambda there's no way to declare them and define separately, or am I wrong?)

Comment: If you don't capture anything, why not just write it as a template function? If you do capture, then I figure you may run into static initialization order issues.

Comment: So you suggest to do this in the following way?
`template <class T>
const auto add(T&& x) {
 return [=](const auto& n) { return n + x; };
};`
Actually it seems to be better. Do you see any disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store them in a header with no problem at all. IF you have the same function with the same arguments it might cause a problem, but if you have different names or arguments, it overloads it and it has no problem.

As for consts, they could be stored in headers simply to use them later in different programs. Just as functions, you could use the constant (defined by you) whenever you need it.

As "side effects" I would say that you could indlude the header in another file and use your function without having to redeclare it.

Comment: "*As for consts, they could be stored in headers simply to use them later in different programs. Just as functions, you could use the constant (defined by you) whenever you need it.*" Unless you use them in a way that causes ODR violations, as @T.C. mentioned...